# go mod tidy with golang1.13 cannot load package

Tags: go, module

When use golang 1.13 with go mod tidy with proxy https://goproxy.cn. I always get the following error:

```
cannot load github.com/astaxie/beego: module github.com/astaxie/beego:
Get https://goproxy.cn/github.com/astaxie/beego/@v/list: 
http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client
```

What is the root cause? Configure or else?

Comment: the upper is in goland. if use command line, the error is "D:\Code\go40\src\rps>go mod tidy
rps imports
        github.com/astaxie/beego: module github.com/astaxie/beego: Get https://goproxy.cn/github.com/astaxie/beego/@v/list: http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client"

Comment: Are you sure goproxy.cn uses https?